# Proof of uniqueness of decomposition into prime knots

Tags: knot-theory

I would like to know the proof of uniqueness of decomposition into prime knots is for a given knot or for a given equivalence class of knots and how to see it. Thanks.

Comment: Googling yields http://www.math.ucla.edu/~radko/191.1.05w/marcos.pdf for one proof.